# c# Linq with complex result

Tags: c#, linq, mapreduce, group-by, ravendb

I have the following class:

```
class Voucher
{
    string AccountId { get; set; }
    Date Date { get; set; } // This class only implements the date part
    decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

with the following data (simplified/sorted for clarification):

```
1 12/02/2014 100
1 12/02/2014 100
1 23/11/2014 100
1 23/11/2014 100
2 10/01/2014 100
2 10/01/2014 100
2 09/08/2014 100
```

I want the result to be grouped by Account and Date but the amount should be the total of all the entries which are less than the Date key:

```
1 12/02/2014 200
1 23/11/2014 400
2 10/01/2014 200
2 09/08/2014 300
```

I cannot think of a solution where I can do this. Grouping with date as the key will give me the total of amounts on that particular date, which I don't require. Can this be done?

Also, I need this to be done in one query as I will use this query for RavenDB reduce.

Comment: I guess it should be `10/01/2015` instead of `2014` is it..? Otherwise 10/01/2014 is also less than 12/02/2014

Comment: It may be worth explicitly stating that you are also grouping by `AccountId`. At least I assume so since everything is less than or equal to `23/11/2014` and your maths only makes sense if you are limiting to within `AccountId` too.

Comment: Why 12/02/2014 has only 200 total amount? 10/01/2014 less than 12/02/2014

Comment: @Chris, I thought it was obvious by the result. My mistake. Edited. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: Updated with multiple group key.

I could do it like this.

Output:

```
var result = from i in input
             group i by new { i.Date.Date, i.AccountId }
             into grouped
             select new {
                 accountId = grouped.Key.AccountId,
                 date = grouped.Key.Date,
                 total = (from kv in input
                          where kv.Date.Date <= grouped.Key.Date && kv.AccountId == grouped.Key.AccountId
                          select kv).Sum(i => i.Amount)
             };
```

Result:

[image]

Input:

```
var input = new[] {
    new Vocuher() {
        AccountId = "1",
        Date = DateTime.Parse("12/02/2014"),
        Amount = 100
    },
    new Vocuher() {
        AccountId = "1",
        Date = DateTime.Parse("12/02/2014"),
        Amount = 100
    },
    new Vocuher() {
        AccountId = "1",
        Date = DateTime.Parse("23/11/2014"),
        Amount = 100
    },
    new Vocuher() {
        AccountId = "1",
        Date = DateTime.Parse("23/11/2014"),
        Amount = 100
    },
    new Vocuher() {
        AccountId = "2",
        Date = DateTime.Parse("10/01/2014"),
        Amount = 100
    },
    new Vocuher() {
        AccountId = "2",
        Date = DateTime.Parse("10/01/2014"),
        Amount = 100
    },
    new Vocuher() {
        AccountId = "2",
        Date = DateTime.Parse("09/08/2014"),
        Amount = 100
    }
};
```